# Evitar que los datos de mi session caduquen en laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, login, session

tengo un problema con los datos del sitio web que estoy desarrollando.

Veran, estoy usando Laravel y el sistema de Login que da el framework. El problema es que luego de un tiempo, los datos se pierden si no hay actividad.

Tengo esta funcion en mi UserModel, que su unico trabajo es devolverme el ID de usuario.

```
public function userID(){
    return $this->id;
}
```

Y en mi controlador 'FichamedicaController', dentro de una funcion, tengo esta linea de codigo que llama a la funcion userID del UserModel.

```
$UserID = $request->User()->userID();
```

El problema es que, por lo general, dejo mi computadora suspendida en lo que voy a almorzar o cenar, y al volver, es como que la session ha caducado, y me arroja un error diciendo que la funcion `userID()` devuelve un null.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y es como que el UserModel no tiene ningun dato cargado y por eso me devuelve un Null.

Intente cambiar el codigo, colocando algo asi en mi controlador, pero aun no me sigue arrojando el error, y el error me lo marca en el controlador.

```
if($request->User()->userID()==null){
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Para que en caso de que me devuelva un null, entonces que me redirija a la pagina de login.
Basicamente, necesito una forma de validar que exista un Usuario y si no existe, redirigirlo al Login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si deseas incrementar el tiempo de sesión puedes utilizar el archivo

```
// config/session.php 
return [
    'lifetime' => 240, //Tiempo en minutos
    .....
```

Por otra parte, hay varios métodos para obtener el Id del usuario como

```
auth()->id;
$request->user()-id;
```

No es necesario crear una función en el modelo, sin embargo, recibes un error por comparas el id de un objeto null, para hacer la comparación debes realizarlo de la siguiente manera

```
if(!$request->user()) {
    // Redirección
}
```

Comment: Genial, muchísimas gracias. Una consulta mas, si estoy usando el sistema de Login que me ofrece Laravel, es necesario las funciones `session_start() y session_destroy()`? o el framework ya maneja todo esto?

Comment: No es necesario